# Lightbox opening in browser window

Tags: html, css

I'm not exactly a web guy, but I did manage to build a very simple site. I have been using Lightbox for many years, and tonight someone on a forum (that I posted a new webpage on), told me that when he clicks to open my lightbox that it is opening in a brower window, and he cannot get my lightbox to work. He claims he's using the latest version of IE on his PC. The weird thing is that nobody else that I have shown this page to is having trouble with my lightbox but this one person. I have noticed sometimes if you don't let a page load completely, and click the lightbox to open, it will not work right, but open in a browser window instead. He told me that he let my page load completely though, and the lightbox is still not working for him. Nobody else on this forum had this problem, but this one guy.

Here is my link:
http://www.bobbysmonstermodels.com/scooby.html

If anyone could please take a look and let me know if my lightbox is working okay for them. My Dad has a PC (I'm on a Mac) and he says it works fine for him. Seems only one person is having issues with it, and I have no clue why.

Comment: It works for me on IE 11. It might be opening in a new window due to graceful fallback. If the browser is unable to run the lightbox JavaScript (or as you point out, someone clicks before the scripts are all loaded), then it'll open in a window instead. If this person is willing to help out, have him check if there are any JavaScript errors on the page. You can check by pressing F12 followed by Ctrl+2.